# How to Pass react native assets file path to native modules ios/android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, assets, react-native-fs

i have some static files in my react native assets folder, i want to pass those files to native modules Android/iOS, is there any way to pass file paths to native modules

Actually i downloading files from s3 using `react-native-fs` to document directory and its giving absolute file path like below

`/Users/jos/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B186BC56-78DC-496B-83D2-3095BCB8BE08/data/Containers/Data/Application/162A2FFD-2B19-4946-8E92-AFE167633AEB/Library/files/Music/prompter.wav`

i'm passing this path to Native Modules and my native modules working fine. But i have some static files in my assets folder i'm sending those paths like `../../assets/demo_songs/music.wav` then my native modules not working. Please help me how to send static assets file paths to native modules

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is the error?

Comment: Hi, my native module is song player, its not playing the song if i send static assets files from react native, and its not generating any error

Comment: Hello @JoshiG Did you found the solution for this ?